# Object array's specific variable value is showing undefined when I console this while its value is showing in array firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello My object array is like in .ts file data coming from firebase

```
var array1 = [
  { 
    name:"rahul",
    address: "address1"
  },
  {
    name:"satya",
    address: "address2"
  },
];
```

code :

```
 public getAllOrdersbyfilterdate2(): Promise<any> {
    var this2 = this;
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.adb.collection('b2borders').get().subscribe((orders) => {
        let data = orders.docs.map(element => {
          let item = element.data();
          item.b2bbranch.get().then(function (doc) {
            item.b2bbranch = doc.data();
            if(item.b2bbranch){
              item.primaryd = this2.db.doc('venue/' + item.b2bbranch.b2bprimary);
              item.primaryd.get().then(function (doc1) {
              item.primarydata = doc1.data();
              });  
              item.name = item.b2bbranch.name; 
              item.address = item.b2bbranch.address; 
            }
          });

          item.id = element.id;
          return item;
        });
        resolve(data);
      }, error => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

When I loop array data and console the name and address then name and address showing undefined in console .

```
array1.forEach(async element => {
  console.log(element.name);
  console.log(element.address);
});
```

While the value is present in array when I console array1 directly

when I pass this value by looping the array in new array then name and address are showing undefined

name is showing undefined and address is showing undefined in new_array in console .
Note: this array1 data is coming from firebase reference and printing only in html but when I console data one by one then it is showing undefined

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: OK I have shown the code

Comment: "the value is present in array when I console array1 directly" Can you show the code for both that, and the case that shows undefined in your question too?